# Account settings crash on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-syncadapter, accountmanager

I have an app working on JB (API 18) with my own account authenticator and sync adapter.
When i run the app on Marshmallow, the app itself is running good, but when i trying to enter my account and sync settings - it crashes.
I mean when i go to phone's Settings->Accounts - the settings app crashes.
When i uninstall my app - the Accounts are shown again.

These are several lines of the Monitor on crash:

```
06-12 11:20:32.519 13938-13938/com.mypackage.myapp E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
06-12 11:20:33.719 7506-7506/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.android.settings, PID: 7506
      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 28620 byte allocation with 5616 free bytes and 5KB until OOM
          at java.lang.reflect.Array.createMultiArray(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:335)
      ...
```

What can be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

After i understood the meaning of the problem, to find the solution was simple.
The icon of the app was too big to show, the memory allocation failed.
Then i just replaced the icon to smaller one.

Interesting that JB can ignore the wrong size and just not to show the icon, but Marshmallow crashes the Settings.